# How to check if string contains a substring in terraform interpolation?

Tags: terraform

How do you check if a terraform string contains another string?

For example, I want to treat terraform workspaces with "tmp" in the name specially (e.g. allowing rds instances to be deleted without a snapshot), so something like this:

```
locals
{
  is_tmp = "${"tmp" in terraform.workspace}"
}
```

As far as I can tell, the [substr interpolation function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#substr-string-offset-length-) doesn't accomplish this.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For terraform 0.12.xx apparently you are suppose to use regexall to do this.

From the manual for terraform 0.12.XX:
[regexall() documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/regexall.html)

> `regexall` can also be used to test whether a particular string matches a given pattern, by testing whether the length of the resulting list of matches is greater than zero.

Example from the manual:

```
> length(regexall("[a-z]+", "1234abcd5678efgh9"))
2

> length(regexall("[a-z]+", "123456789")) > 0
false
```

Example applied to your case in terraform 0.12.xx syntax should be something like:

```
locals
{
  is_tmp = length(regexall(".*tmp.*", terraform.workspace)) > 0
}
```

It also specifically says in the manual not to use "regex" but instead use regexall.

If the given pattern does not match at all, the regex raises an error. To test whether a given pattern matches a string, use regexall and test that the result has length greater than zero.

As stated above this is because you will actually get an exception error when you try to use it in the later versions of 0.12.xx that are out now when you run plan.  This is how I found this out and why I posted the new answer back here.

Comment: Looks like there's a feature request and PR for something more elegant, but no attention from hashicorp for some reason: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27198

Comment: Looks like the PR has been merged, [answer by Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76477280/7046260) provides the most up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 34):

You can indirectly check for substrings using [replace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#replace-string-search-replace-), e.g.

```
locals
{
  is_tmp = "${replace(terraform.workspace, "tmp", "") != terraform.workspace}"
}
```

Comment: I hope this isn't the best answer.  Also as far as I can tell I can't define a terraform `contains` function (I guess I could define a `contains` terraform module that does this, but the module instantiation would be more verbose than just copying this logic).

Comment: quite sad that the `contains` function only works with lists.. I have strings that contain separators so i can use `split` to test ... but it will break if in the future we change separators or something else... :(

Comment: As an example to use split as suggested by @VincentDeSmet 

`enabled = "${contains(split(".", var.instance_type), "t2") ? false : true }"`

Answer (score 16):

Terraform introduced `strcontains` in the most [recent version](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/strcontains) (v1.5.0) which can be used here:

```
locals {
    substring_present = strcontains(mystring, mysubstring) # returns True
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [MechaStorm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57633930/2745495), with Terraform 0.12.7+, you can use `regex` to return a Boolean value if your string contains a particular substring:

```
locals {
  is_tmp = contains(regex("^(?:.*(tmp))?.*$",terraform.workspace),"tmp")
}
```

The `regex` query returns a list of capture groups for any characters before "tmp", "tmp" if found, any characters after "tmp".  Then, `contains` looks for "tmp" in the list and returns true or false.

Answer (score 4):

The length of the list produced by the [split](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/split.html) function is greater than one when the separator is a substring.

```
locals {
  is_tmp = length(split("tmp", terraform.workspace)) > 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [replace( string, search, replace )](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#replace-string-search-replace-) as in the snippet:

```
// string contains ABBA = result is ABBA
output "match" {
  value = "${ replace("xxxABBAyyy", "/(?:.*)(ABBA)(?:.*)/", "$1") }"
}
// string doesn't contain ABBA = result is original string
output "no_match" {
  value = "${ replace("xxxBABAyyy", "/(?:.*)(ABBA)(?:.*)/", "$1")}"
}
// string contains ABBA (ingorecase) = result is AbBA
output "equals_ignorecase" {
  value = "${ replace("xxxAbBAyyy", "/(?:.*)((?i)ABBA)(?:.*)/", "$1")}"
}
```

An output of `terraform apply` is:

```
Outputs:

equals_ignorecase = AbBA
match = ABBA
no_match = xxxBABAyyy
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that makes sense reading, IMHO:

```
locals {
  is_tmp = can(regex("tmp", terraform.workspace))
}
```

This works because the regex function will raise an error if no matches are found.

Bonus: since Terraform 1.3.x, there are the new [startswith](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/startswith) and [endswith](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/endswith) functions that can be handy in a good amount of cases.

Answer (score 0):

In terraform 0.12.7, we now have [regex](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/regex.html) . This may help simplify some code and make it readable to some (perhaps?)

```
> regex("[a-z]+", "53453453.345345aaabbbccc23454")
aaabbbccc
```

Comment: This would throw an error if no match is found. Using `regexall()` with `length(regexall()) > 0` check is preferred to keep it graceful.  Example shared by @isaacegglestone here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193941/636762

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to check if bucket name start with test-tmp
eg. test-tmp, test-tmp-app1, test-tmp-db1 etc..

```
is_test_bucket = can(regex("^(test-tmp){1}($|-{1}.*$)", var.bucket_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.5.0, terraform supports the strcontains method to do this.

Ref: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/strcontains

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34847723)