# How to whitelist Atlassian/Bitbucket IPs in AWS EC2 security group?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, bitbucket

We want Bitbucket webhooks to trigger our CI tool which runs on an AWS EC2 instance, protected with ingress rules from general access.

Bitbucket provides a page listing their IP addresses at https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall/

They also have a machine-consumable version at https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/ for Atlassian IPs in general.

I wonder, what is an efficient approach to add and maintain this list in AWS EC2 security groups, e.g. via terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up scraping the machine-consumable json from their page, and let terraform manage the rest. The step of getting the json is left as a manual task.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "bitbucket-ips-sgr" {
  security_group_id = "your-security-group-id"
  type = "ingress"

  from_port = 443
  to_port = 443
  protocol = "TCP"
  cidr_blocks = local.bitbucket_cidrs_ipv4
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = local.bitbucket_cidrs_ipv6
}

locals {
  bitbucket_cidrs_ipv4 = [for item in local.bitbucket_ip_ranges_source.items:
  # see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243474/1242922
  item.cidr if length(regexall(":", item.cidr)) == 0
  ]
  bitbucket_cidrs_ipv6 = [for item in local.bitbucket_ip_ranges_source.items:
  # see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47243474/1242922
  item.cidr if length(regexall(":", item.cidr)) > 0
  ]
  # the list originates from https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/
  bitbucket_ip_ranges_source = jsondecode(
<<JSON
the json output from the above URL
JSON
          )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I improved on Richard's answer and wanted to add that TF's http provider can fetch the JSON for you, and, with a slight tweak to the `jsondecode()` call, that same `for` loop still plays.

```
provider "http" {}

data "http" "bitbucket_ips" {
  url = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/"

  request_headers = {
    Accept = "application/json"
  }
}

locals {
  bitbucket_ipv4_cidrs = [for c in jsondecode(data.http.bitbucket_ips.body).items : c.cidr if length(regexall(":", c.cidr)) == 0]
  bitbucket_ipv6_cidrs = [for c in jsondecode(data.http.bitbucket_ips.body).items : c.cidr if length(regexall(":", c.cidr)) > 0]
}

output "ipv4_cidrs" {
  value = local.bitbucket_ipv4_cidrs
}

output "ipv6_cidrs" {
  value = local.bitbucket_ipv6_cidrs
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear :) Amazing, thanks for the improvement, very clear. Is it possible to control when to fetch the list anew? I assume it will do so on every tf apply.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post to give it more a standalone-answer feeling than a thread-discussion. :)

Comment: You assume correctly! The data lookup would run every time in this implementation. Skipping it (i.e. with a control variable and a ternary `count` on the `data` lookup) would result in an empty value when the referring resource calls it, and Terraform would see 
 all of the Bitbucket CIDRs as drift to be removed. If your use case calls for strict control over when changes are introduced, then the manual scrape/hard-coded JSON method would be a better choice.