# Terraform contains(...) - how to check for wildcard or prefix

Tags: terraform, devops

Is there a way I can check if a variable in Terraform contains a specific substring, i.e. en environment prefix such as `eu-` or `us-`? Please, see the following to better understand what I want to do.

`contains("eu-<...>", var.environment) ? do-something : do-something-else`

`<...>` could be anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if string contains a substring in terraform interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243474/how-to-check-if-string-contains-a-substring-in-terraform-interpolation)

Comment: There are more answers and more recent better answers available in more recent versions at the link provided by @GinoMempin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`regexall`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regexall):

```
length(regexall("eu-", var.environment)) > 0
```

For example:

```
variable environment {
  default = "eu-dev-environment"
}

locals {
  contains = length(regexall("eu-", var.environment)) > 0
}
```

The value for `contains` will be `true` in this case.