# Match strings from one list in another list in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a set of databricks clusters using the databricks terraform provider. Each of these clusters needs to have its own instance profile. So I need to generate such a map to loop through:

```json
{
  cluster1: profile1,
  cluster2: profile2,
  cluster3: profile3

}
```

and so on. I currently have a list of clusters like this:

```hcl
cluster_envs = [
    "client1-dev-cluster1",
    "client1-dev-cluster2",
    "client1-prod-cluster1",
    "client1-prod-cluster2",
]
```

And I have a separate, unconnected list of instance profiles like this:

```hcl
databricks_instance_profiles = [
    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_account_ID>:instance-profile/databricks-client1-dev-instance_profile",
    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_account_ID>:instance-profile/databricks-client1-prod-instance_profile",
    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_account_ID>:instance-profile/databricks-client2-dev-instance_profile",
    "arn:aws:iam::<AWS_account_ID>:instance-profile/databricks-client2-prod-instance_profile",
]
```

I'd like to remove the `-clusterN` part of the cluster_envs and find the matching instance profile(pseudocode):

```
for env in local.cluster_envs :
    for arn in local.databricks_instance_profiles:
       if (substring of env without clusterN) matches arn: arn
```

The end result should be that I can use this generated map like this

```hcl
resource "databricks_cluster" "multi_tenant" {
  for_each                  =  <generated_map>
  cluster_name              = each.key
  spark_version             = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id

  aws_attributes {
    zone_id                 = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
    instance_profile_arn    = each.value
  }
  
  custom_tags = var.tags
}
```

The closest hint I have is to use [regexall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243474/how-to-check-if-string-contains-a-substring-in-terraform-interpolation) but I'm not able to get it to work when both the arguments to regexall are variables.

What I've tried:

```hcl
temp_cluster_envs = flatten([
    for env in local.cluster_envs : [
      for arn in local.databricks_instance_profiles: map(env, arn) if regexall(
        join("-", [
          split("-", env)[0],
          split("-", env)[1],
          split("-", env)[2]
      ]), arn)
    ]
  ])
```

gives me the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid 'for' condition
│
│   on modules/manage-workspaces/locals.tf line 93, in locals:
│   92:     for env in local.cluster_envs : [
│   93:       for arn in local.databricks_instance_profiles: map(env, arn) if regexall(
│   94:         join("-", [
│   95:           split("-", env)[0],
│   96:           split("-", env)[1],
│   97:           split("-", env)[2]
│   98:       ]), arn)
│   99:     ]
│
│ The 'if' clause value is invalid: bool required.
╵
```

Answer (score 0):

`regexall()` doesn't return a true/false boolean value, it returns a list of matches. The error message is clearly telling you an `if` clause must be a boolean value, not a list.

If you look at [the official documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regexall) for `regexall()` there's an example right there for turning `regexall()` into a boolean value by wrapping it in `length() > 0`.

In your code that would look like:

```
temp_cluster_envs = flatten([
    for env in local.cluster_envs : [
      for arn in local.databricks_instance_profiles: map(env, arn) if length(regexall(
        join("-", [
          split("-", env)[0],
          split("-", env)[1],
          split("-", env)[2]
      ]), arn)) > 0
    ]
  ])
```